# Car lost power. New alternator, new battery, and just had an oil change

Tags: toyota, yaris, stall

I am hoping this was my mistake. My apartment has a steep hill to go down for the garage. I went to turn the corner and noticed the garage was opening. I pressed on the break, put my car in reverse. When I went to hit the accelerator, my car started rolling down the hill. I panicked and put my car into drive immediately. The person in the garage waited until I got in to move. When my car started to slow down, I hit the gas and my car locked up and stalled. I was able to get it into my parking space. I turned off my car and restarted it. I was able to back up and drive forward again. I have a 2009 Toyota Yaris with 131,000 miles on it. I fixed the alternator about 2 months ago, new battery about 6 months old, and an oil change was done today. I am hoping I just mistreated my car, and put it from reverse to drive too soon.

Answer (score 3):

"I am hoping I just mistreated my car, and put it from reverse to drive too soon."

More than likely. Modern transmissions have safety features that don't allow you to actually engage into reverse without reaching a desired slowed speed. If you panicked and threw it into reverse without actually coming to a complete stop, the transmission would basically ignore your request for it to go into reverse until you had slowed down enough for it to catch. There is a certain "pin" present in modern transmissions that attempt to catch the gears before moving them. With your car rolling down the hill, the pin wouldn't be able to catch and you would probably hearing a ratcheting noise as you rolled. You probably didn't do any damage this time, but it's not advisable to attempt again in the future.

Comment: Thanks! I did not hear a sound. I just saw that the power cut, and my car seized like it did when my battery died. Now, it seems like my break pedal is sticky. I only get that after driving 10 miles.